# Unity with web api sample IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, katana, identityserver3

I'm trying to use this project from the IdentityServer3 samples,
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/SampleAspNetWebApi
for web api services, and I'd like to use Unity as my Dependency Injection strategy and I got it from nuget package "Unity.WebApi" so, It creates a new file inside my app_start folder where we have to register our types, in my case I have just one interface. like this

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IApp, AppService>();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

and in my Apicontroller just one constructor

```
private readonly IApp _App;
private TDataController(IApp app)
{ _App = app; }
```

and this my configuration method at the startup class

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary();

    app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://localhost:44333/core",
        RequiredScopes = new[] { "write" }
    });
    UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
    app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());
}
```

So, very simple, isn't it?
But I don't know what I'm missing, because the thing is that when I try to invoke one simple action from my controller it throws me an error:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error
>   occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TDataController'.
>   Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public
>   constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at ..................

PS: If Dominick Baier read this question I'd like to say sorry about my post on his issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved myself, and this is the way I did.

If you see in my startup class I have this:

```
app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());
```

So, on that method, I added this line to use my dependencyresolver

```
public static HttpConfiguration Register()
{
    config.DependencyResolver = UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
    return config;
}
```

and I changed the return type of UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(); to

```
public static UnityDependencyResolver RegisterComponents()
{....
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    ///here all my registertypes
    return new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

and that's the way to resolve this problem with unity, I hope it helps.